# How could I escaped character in query string

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to query SAMPLE_WEBSITE with POST method,

How could  I convert original string into encoded string

So that I can query with Python requests, thanks

Eg. 11/28/2015 -> 11%2F28%2F2015

```
data = '&availab
ility.Info.Stations%5B0%5D.DepartureDate=11%2F28%2F2015


 requests.post('http://SAMPLE_WEBSITE',data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`urllib.quote_plus()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) to encode a string

```
>>> import urllib
>>> date = "11/28/2015"
>>> urllib.quote_plus(date)
'11%2F28%2F2015'
```

Or if you have a dictionary you can use [`urllib.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

```
>>> import urllib
>>> mapping = {'availability.Info.Stations[0]': '11/28/2015'}
>>> data = urllib.urlencode(mapping)
>>> data
'availability.Info.Stations%5B0%5D=11%2F28%2F2015'
```